# WKWebView Reader View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios8, wkwebview

I am switching from `UIWebView` to **`WKWebView`**, and **can't figure out how to set up my configuration for using `Reader`**.
[image]

Is there anyone that can help me?

`viewDidLoad`:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [NSClassFromString(@"WKWebViewConfiguration") alloc] init];
    // Configuration of Reader goes here?
    wkWebView = [[wkWebViewClass alloc] initWithFrame:frame configuration:config];
    [self.view addSubview:wkWebView];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot enable "Reader" mode for WKWebView (or UIWebView).

Edit: You can however do this with SFSafariViewController as seen in the other solution.

It occurs to me that it would be possible to modify the HTML code of the website to make it look more like Reader. It seems that there are services that already do this, like Readability:

Just load this URL into your WKWebView:
http://www.readability.com/m?url=YOUR_URL_HERE

This should help you achieve a similar function to Reader.

Comment: Cool good to know there's no way to do it.  Have checked into the Readability stuff before.  Just assumed Apple gave the power in WKWebKit to access their Reader mode.

Comment: Readability.com is no longer available

Answer (score 8):

Just improve @dzensik answer, because 'init(url:entersReaderIfAvailable:)' was deprecated in iOS 11.0.

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(true)

            let urlString = "http://google.com"
            let url = URL(string: urlString)
            let configuration = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
            configuration.entersReaderIfAvailable = true

            let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url!, configuration: configuration)
            present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

@dfmuir is right, UIWebView or WKWebView do not provide a Reader Mode. However as Baig said you can use a SFSafariViewController to achieve this. Here we go with a simple and working Swift code to do so:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        let urlString = "http://google.com"
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url!, entersReaderIfAvailable: true)
        present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I needed to enter Reader view by default on a url in Swift 3.

Answer (score 3):

First things first: import SafariServices:

```
#import <SafariServices/SafariServices.h>
```

Afterwards we are instantiating SFSafariViewController and adding it as a subview. We have two options doing so:

- Creating with only base URL
- Creating with bas URL as well as entering 'Reading Mode' in case it is available

> ```
> NSString *sURL = @"http://google.com";
>
> NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];
>
> SFSafariViewController *safari = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL]; // 1.
>
> SFSafariViewController *safari = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:URL entersReaderIfAvailable:YES]; // 2.
>
> [self presentViewController:safari animated:YES completion:nil];
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to enable reader view.

Just use this code…

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerText”)
```

This code is getting a the text in the Web Page

Here is the whole code for reader view

```
@IBAction func readerViewtoogle(_ sender: Any) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerText") { result, error in
            print(result!)
            self.webView.loadHTMLString("""
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <style>
h1{
font-weight: normal;
align="justify";
color: grey;
line-height: 1.6;
}
                </style>
                <head>
                <title>Error</title>
                </head>
                <body style="background-color:black">
                <h1 style="text-align:center;">\(String(describing: self.webView.title))</h1>
                <br>
                <hr>
                <h1 style="text-align:justify;">\(String(describing: result))</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                </body>
                </html>
""", baseURL: self.webView.url)
        }
    }
```

Done with Xcode 12 beta